# Command line steps of SCCM image capture tool

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, sccm

I am trying to create an image of the windows VM by mounting the SCCM image capture tool to the VM and running the Image Capture Wizard from the Removal Storage (D drive) where the image capture tool was attached.

I am aware of the manual steps that I have to go through of the image capture wizard but I want to script these steps. Is there a command line / powershell way to automate these where I can enter the destination , account name and password and get the image captured. Screenshots of the steps that I wish to automate.
[image: SCREENSHOT 1]
[image: SCREENSHOT 2]

Comment: are you also aware that you can use a fully automated build and capture task sequence that does all the steps for you? Or would this qualify?

Comment: I am not very familiar with SCCM. I am new to windows automation in general. I know that some steps can be automated using task sequence but I would like to automate everything and create a script instead of running a task sequence from GUI. Is that a possibility ? Can I also run task sequence from command line ? If so how ?

Comment: the build and capture ts is not really designed to be triggered via script but rather that you start vm with the assigned ts via pxe boot and then all steps from there on are taken automatically. I wrote that in more detail as an answer although I am not 100% it will meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The official way to get automated capture would be building a fully automated build and capture task sequence. The official ms documentation would be [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb633062.aspx) but you can also find many more detailed unofficial guides for this like [this one](https://www.systemcenterdudes.com/sccm-windows-10-build-and-capture-task-sequence/) for example.

The idea here is that you deploy an operating system from source image, then automatically install updates, install all software you want via applications or programs, change all settings via scripts and automatically capture the output again as a sysprepped os image for further osd. The whole thing is completely unattended (in theory up to the point where you could configure your vm in a way that it would capture an image on every start)

If you want to only automate the capture but not the build you should be able to just use half of this TS, namely the capture part.

While this is fully automated and can be done unattended it is not per se really thought to be triggered via command line. You can probably script a task sequence trigger but it is not how the system was intended so I would not really recommend going this way if this is your first time using sccm.